# Переход по push уведомлению с авторизацией и открытием карточки товара

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, авторизация, push-уведомления

Есть приложение состоящее из:
Activity1 - окно авторизации
Activity2 - окно основного приложения, в нем список товаров
Activity3 - окно карточка товара (при нажатии на одно из поле списка в активити2 выдается карточка товара)

Есть push уведомления по товару.
Допустим приходит push уведомление на товар№642446, при нажатии должна открыться карточка Activity3.
Но так как приложение закрыто, оно упирается на Activity1 ввода логина пароля.

Какие образом, авторизоваться и открыть карточку Activity3 ?

У меня мысли такие:
Тут два случая приложение открыто и закрыто.

1. открыто, сразу можно перейти на Activity3
2. закрыто , при нажатии на уведомление сделать переход на Activity1 передать id товара. В Activity1 в onCreate  проверить. если значение
   товара существует и логин пароль тоже заранее был сохранен сделать
   переход на Activity3 ?